# Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row - Garbage Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, data-conversion

I'm trying to bulk insert data from a TXT file (file has some formatting), into SQLServer 2008 using VB sub routine in an ASPX page.

The TXT file has the following data

```
            AWS SERVICES-PM                   |Regular
```

But the temp file created for the upload contains some gibberish value

```
           AWS SERVICES-PMï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½           |Regular
```

This is the code used to create the temp file from the original file

```
 For i = 0 To count - 1

        If lines(i).Contains("---------") Then
            lines.RemoveAt(i)
        End If
        If lines(i).Contains("Dynamic List Display") Then
            lines.RemoveAt(i)
        End If
        If lines(i).Contains("Network description") Then
            lines.RemoveAt(i)
        End If
    Next

     Dim fileNameRelPath As String
    fileNameRelPath = "~\Files\SAPDOWNLOAD\TempFile_UploadToSQL.txt"
    Dim fileNamePath As String
    fileNamePath = Server.MapPath(fileNameRelPath)

    If IO.File.Exists(fileNamePath) Then
        Kill(fileNamePath)
    End If

    IO.File.WriteAllLines(fileNamePath, lines.ToArray())
```

This is the command i'm using to bulk insert

```
 " BULK INSERT Timedata_Upload FROM '" + fullPath + "' WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')"
```

I get Bulk insert data conversion error due to the above gibberish values.
Where do you think I'm making a mistake ?